# Stacktrace = ** [{erlang,nif_error,[undefined],[]}

Tags: erlang

- I have a `OTP - 19.3.6` environment.
- I am trying to use a library that depends on `OTP - 22`.
- So, I am trying to use and write `compatibilities` to use that library.
- For eg. I ran into `string:lowercase` and `unicode_util`, issues, so I found a compat lib to get past those issues: https://github.com/benoitc/unicode_util_compat
- Then I ran into `maps:iterator` and `maps:next` issues.
- Based on my limited `erlang` understanding, I tried to write `maps_compat.erl`
- I got past `maps:iterator` and `maps:next` issues.
- However, I got this error where `map_next` is `erts_internal.erl` function:

  ```
  Stacktrace =
    **  [{erlang,nif_error,[undefined],[]},
            {maps_compat,map_next,3, [{file,"../apns_v2_otp_19.3.6/_build/default/lib/xxx/src/maps_compat.erl"}
  ```

from https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/preloaded/src/erts_internal.erl

```
%% return the next assoc in the iterator and a new iterator
-spec map_next(I, M, A) -> {K,V,NI} | list() when
      I :: non_neg_integer(),
      M :: map(),
      K :: term(),
      V :: term(),
      A :: iterator | list(),
      NI :: maps:iterator().

map_next(_I, _M, _A) ->
    erlang:nif_error(undefined).
```

I modified the above function in my `maps_compat.erl` as

```
%% return the next assoc in the iterator and a new iterator
-spec map_next(I, M, A) -> {K,V,NI} | list() when
      I :: non_neg_integer(),
      M :: map(),
      K :: term(),
      V :: term(),
      A :: iterator | list(),
      NI :: iterator().

map_next(_I, _M, _A) ->
    erlang:nif_error(undefined).
```

but it failed with the error above.

- Can this issue be fixed?
- If so, how can I fix this?
- Is there a `maps_compat` library already such as `unicode_util_compat`?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion in https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/4595, I implemented this to not get this error anymore.

```
maps_iterator(Map) ->
    maps:to_list(Map).

maps_next([{K,V} | T]) ->
    {K, V, T};
maps_next([]) ->
    none.
```